# Get my Location with Flash

Tags: flash

is it possible to show my Town (find by IP) / Town of my Provider in Flash File?

Maybe there are some libs for this.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the ActionScript 3.0 IPinfodb API here:

http://creative-geeks.com/blog/2009/06/09/ipinfodb-actionscript-30-api/

Comment: Original sources in the link are taken from here http://ipinfodb.com/flash_ip_info.php

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would be better to use server side language to take the IP and location and pass that to the Flash application. e.g PHP, ASP

Also you can have a look at that:
http://ipinfodb.com/flash_ip_info.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to get the IP location with PHP you can check this tutorial:
http://creative-geeks.com/blog/2012/05/06/getting-ip-information-with-php-and-curl/

You can then pass the IP location data to the SWF file. That's how usually hook it up, because then I'm not limited to ActionScript and enables me to use the same function for other non ActionScript projects. This method also increases code centralization.